# simply launch method in objective-c

Tags: ios, methods

I try to implement method in my program.
I search in the documentation since 2 hours but nothing is clear.
The purpose is to launch a mediaPicker in the code. Just that.

Here I put the method I try to launch

```
      @implementation ViewController

- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
   didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {

    mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    [[mediaPicker view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    mediaPicker.delegate      = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    mediaPicker.prompt      = NSLocalizedString (@"AddSongsPrompt", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated: YES];


}
```

And in - (void)viewDidLoad

I want to launch this method. I try all of this

```
    MPMediaPickerController * media;
    [media mediaPicker]; // error
   ViewController * media;
    MPMediaPickerController * mediaPicker;
    MPMediaItemCollection * didPickMediaItems;
    [media mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *) didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)]; // error
```

Somebody could support?
Thanks in advance

Comment: both are in same view controller